# Need random player spawn locations on only certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a simple 2d game where the players will be placed randomly when the game starts. Right now they spawn anywhere on the map. I need to have them only spawn on tiles with a class of "sand". This is my code so far:

```
var X = Math.floor((Math.random() * 19) + 1) * 40;
var Y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 19) + 1) * 40;      

function addplayer1() {
  var player1 = '<div id="player1"></div>';
  $("#map").append(player1);
  $("#player1").css({
    top: X, 
    left: Y, 
    position: "absolute"
  });
};

addplayer1();
```

I am stuck on this. It is my first game. I think I need an if statement after I create my X and Y variables. Can anybody help or point me towards a tutorial?

Comment: Where are these `tiles` ? How do you know that a certain `tile` is sandy?

Comment: You've not really given enough information to give you a full example, but I'd suggest placing the `.sand` elements in to an array then picking one at random. Then you can position the player on that element

Comment: The map is generated with a random array (0s and 1s) and all tiles have a class of sand or stone. So now I need the players to only spawn on sand.

Answer (score 0):

Generate the spawn, and if the tile is not sand, redo the entire thing. You would use some checking function to see if they are on a sand tile, and if they are not, respawn them by removing the previous player and use the `addplayer1()` function.